# Не работает анимация в тильде

Tags: html, css, анимация

Есть код, но анимация увеличения не работает, то есть изображение плавно увеличивается, но без плавности возвращается в первоначальное положение.

**Как сделать так, чтобы вся анимация работала плавно?**

```
<style>
    .tn-elem__1630375871470210224069 {
        transition: 1s ease-out;
    }

    .tn-elem__1630375871470210224069 :hover {
        opacity: 0.6;
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Убрать пробел между классом элемента и `:hover`

```
.tn-elem__1630375871470210224069 :hover {
```

И заменить `ease-out` на `ease-in-out`.

Должно ваши потребности закрыть.

```css
.tn-elem__1630375871470210224069 {
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #000;
  margin: auto;
}

.tn-elem__1630375871470210224069:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="tn-elem__1630375871470210224069">

</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло))

Comment: @Tslyme пожалуйста. Буду благодарен за выбор ответа как решение и стрелку вверх. Я тут ради репутации